# Execute shell command using Python subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

I want to execute the following command via a python script:

```
sudo cat </dev/tcp/time.nist.gov/13
```

I can execute this command via the command line completely fine. However, when I execute it using subprocess, I get an error:

```
Command ['sudo','cat','</dev/tcp/time.nist.gov/13'] returned non-zero exit status 1
```

My code is as follows

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_output(['sudo','cat','</dev/tcp/time.nist.gov/13'])
```

As I mentioned above, executing the command via the command line gives the desired output without any error. I am using the Raspbian Jessie OS. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: The redirection operator `<` is part of shell functionality. Your call doesn't use the shell so `cat` processes the parameter directly (and doesn't understand it)

Comment: @MichaelButscher Thanks for the reply. How do I execute this command using subprocess then?

Comment: `check_output` supports a `shell` parameter for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to use `subprocess` for this at all.

What does this command really do?  It uses a bash extension to open a network socket, feeds it through **cat**(1) to reroute it to standard output, and decides to run cat as root.  You don't really need the bash extension, or `/bin/cat`, or root privileges to do any of this in Python; you're looking for the [socket](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html) library.

Here's an all-Python equivalent:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import socket
s = socket.create_connection(('time.nist.gov', 13))
try:
    print(s.recv(4096))
finally:
    s.close()
```

(Note that all of my experimentation suggests that this connection works but the daytime server responds by closing immediately.  For instance, the simpler shell invocation `nc time.nist.gov 13` also returns empty string.)

Comment: Works. Thanks :)

Comment: Can you explain why subprocess is the wrong way to approach this? Besides the fact it isn't working for Umar haha

Comment: In general it's both easier and faster to try to do things natively in a single language if you can.  If you're using `subprocess` for basic file I/O (ls cat grep sed ...) (or in this case, network I/O) you should just use your local language primitives for it instead.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
import subprocess

com = "sudo cat </dev/tcp/time.nist.gov/13"

subprocess.Popen(com, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, shell = True)
```

Comment: Doesnt work, error: cannot open /dev/tcp/time.nist.gov/13L No such file or directory

Comment: Turn it into the full path. I don't know what that is on your pc. Ie, C:/User/.../dev/tcp/time.nist.gov/13. Or put the script into the same folder as the application you are trying to call.